# Birthday paradox for statement/calcutions

Tags: c++

Apparently I was actually suppose to create an array that randomly assigns birthdays over many trials (5000). It's then suppose to count up each time there is at least 2 birthdays for 2 - 50 people and divide the outcome by 5,000 to get the approximate probability. I believe I have my loops messed up and would like some feedback. Not code, I would like to understand exactly what is going wrong and how I messed it up.

```
int main()
{
    const int trials(5000);
    double total;
    int count(0), birthdays[49];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 2; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < trials; k++)
        {
            fillUp(birthdays, 49);
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= 50; j++)
            {
                if (birthdays[i] == birthdays[j])
                {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        total = count / 5000.0;
        cout << "For " << i << " the probability is " << total << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void fillUp(int birthdays [], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        birthdays[i] = rand() % 365 + 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
For 2 the probability is 0.1286
For 3 the probability is 0.2604
...
...
For 49 the probability is 3.9424
For 50 the probability is 3.9424
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the values of some of your variables to see where it's going wrong?

Comment: You have your formula wrong. Look closely.

Comment: I remember hearing about the birthday problem from my discrete math class. I don't remember everything about the problem, but you don't use the variable "people" anywhere in your code outside of the declaration. Could this be related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence you have created a new question, so I will create a new answer. Right now you keep changing the birthdays while you are looping over them; this is why things don't work. You need two nested loops to test for equal birthdays (or if you are smart you sort them, then only check adjacent ones. It is probably faster with n = 50.)

You also need to start testing at the first birthday (your array is base 0 - but you start with i = 2). And for each trial, you can see how many people you need to compare before you have a match. The correct code will look something like this (note that I run 5000 trials for each number of people in the room; you could be more efficient by checking for a match when you have 3,4,5... people based on the same sample, but then there would be some correlation in the sampling).

**EDITED** - tested this code, seems to compile and run OK. Results look close to expected values.

```
#include <iostream>

void fillUp(int birthdays [], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        birthdays[i] = rand() % 365 + 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
int birthdays[50];
int trials = 5000;
int flag;
double total;
int collisions[50];
   // number of people "in the room"
   for (int i = 2; i < 50; i++)
      {
      collisions[i] = 0;
      // do 5000 trials:
      for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++)
       {
        fillUp(birthdays, i);
        flag = 0;
        // compare all pairs (j,k):
        for (int j = 0; j < i - 1 && flag == 0; j++)
        {
          for (int k = j + 1; k < i && flag == 0; k++ )
          {
            if (birthdays[k] == birthdays[j])
            {
              collisions[i]++;
              flag = 1;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    total = collisions[i] / 5000.0;
    std::cout << "For " << i << " people in the room the probability is " << total << std::endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Note - I did not have a chance to compile / test this; it should be right "in essence". Let me know if it gives a problem.

Comment: The output starts at -171799, slowly fluctuates to -171796, then back to -171799.

Comment: @CPTKirk - when I had a chance to test I found a number of problems. The one you saw was probably due to the mixing of `ii` and `i`, and not initializing the values in `collisions` explicitly. Thanks for letting me know. Does it work for you now?

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the C++ code; you just have a typo in your math. It should be:

```
power = (num * (num - 1.0) / 2.0);
chance = 1.0 - pow(constant, power);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may know the formula, but your code is not implementing it correctly. Here is some C code that implements the formula correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  double p;
  int ii;
  int people;
  for (people = 3; people < 50; people++) {
    p = 1;
    for (ii = 1; ii < people; ii++) {
      p *= (365.0 - ii) / 365.0;
    }
    printf("for %d people, probability is %.4f\n", people, 1 - p);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
for 1 people, probability is 0.0000
for 2 people, probability is 0.0027
for 3 people, probability is 0.0082
for 4 people, probability is 0.0164
for 5 people, probability is 0.0271
for 6 people, probability is 0.0405
for 7 people, probability is 0.0562
for 8 people, probability is 0.0743
for 9 people, probability is 0.0946
for 10 people, probability is 0.1169
for 11 people, probability is 0.1411
for 12 people, probability is 0.1670
for 13 people, probability is 0.1944
for 14 people, probability is 0.2231
for 15 people, probability is 0.2529
for 16 people, probability is 0.2836
for 17 people, probability is 0.3150
for 18 people, probability is 0.3469
for 19 people, probability is 0.3791
for 20 people, probability is 0.4114
for 21 people, probability is 0.4437
for 22 people, probability is 0.4757
for 23 people, probability is 0.5073
for 24 people, probability is 0.5383
for 25 people, probability is 0.5687
for 26 people, probability is 0.5982
for 27 people, probability is 0.6269
for 28 people, probability is 0.6545
for 29 people, probability is 0.6810
```

Leading to the familiar result that "the chance is > 50% with just 23 people".

Comment: I think you meant to iterate till ``ii < people``. Otherwise your formula gives an obviously incorrect prediction for ``people = 1``.

Comment: @Bogdan - I believe you are right - I have modified. And dasblinkenlight correctly points out this is the exact formula - the one OP was trying to use was only approximately correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating 364/365 ≈ 0.0027 to the power of some large number, which results in a number only very slightly above zero. When rounded to the requested output precision, this results in zero.